# Only include later subdirectories in file string C#

Tags: c#, string, directory

I'm trying to write a nifty content loader in XNA to avoid having to individually load each asset. However, I'm having trouble describing directory locations because the default directory for File operations is the location of the exe, but XNA's Content.Load uses a default directory of the Content folder.

```
foreach (string subD in Directory.GetDirectories("..\\..\\..\\..\\Happy WorkerContent\\gfx\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(subD))
    {
        string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Tex), file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subD);
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            GXDict.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s), GV.C_Game1.Content.Load<Texture2D>(subD + "\\" + file));
        }
    }
}
```

My error is because subD is, for example, "........\Happy WorkerContent\gfx\level entities\terrains", but Content.Load expects "gfx\level entities\terrains".

I could do something like subD.Substring(32), but this seems messy, especially if I rename any folders or anything later (and may not work in the published version?). Is there a good way to say "I only want the part of the file which is after the "Happy WorkerContent" directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method to return the text following a particular target string.

Then if you needed to search for a different string, you'd just need to pass a different target string to the method.

For example:

```
// Returns the contents of text following the target string,
// or "" if the target string wasn't found.

public static string ContentAfter(string text, string target)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(target);

    if (index >= 0)
        return text.Substring(index + target.Length);
    else
        return "";
}
```

Then you'd call it like:

```
string test = "..\\..\\..\\..\\Happy WorkerContent\\gfx\\whatever";
string target = "\\Happy WorkerContent\\";

string following = ContentAfter(test, target);
```

That wouldn't work so great if you had two strings matching the target string in the text. The method would return all the text after the *first* match, which would include the second target string of course.